# Separating streams in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, input, vector

```
    int n = 1; 

    //Lines 14 to (vertices+13) read
    while (i<(vertices+14))
    {
        //First three numbers on each line put into "v1"
        if (n < 4)
        {
            copy(istream_iterator<float>(input), 
            istream_iterator<float>(), 
            back_inserter(v1));

            n++;
        }

        //Last three numbers on each line put into "v2"
        else
        {
            copy(istream_iterator<float>(input), 
            istream_iterator<float>(), 
            back_inserter(v2));
            n++;

            if (n > 6)
            {
                i++;    
                n=1;    
            }
        }
```

This is supposed to sort the first three numbers on a line into one vector and the last three numbers into another vector. However due to what I suspect is the nature of how streams work, all the numbers are going into vector v1, and none are going into v2. Input is an ifstream.

Comment: You misunderstand what `std::copy` does – read the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to how [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) works.

The second parameter marks where to stop copying, and your parameter

```
istream_iterator<float>()
```

represents "The *end* of the stream".  The **first** call to `copy` is reading the entire stream.

Use [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) instead to copy a certain quantity.

*From comment:*

> Is there also a way of using the second parameter of copy to get three numbers?

That's precisely what it's for.  For some number *n*, if you want to copy *n* values, use `std::copy_n`.

Comment: `copy_n(inputFile.begin,3,back_inserter(anatomy));`
Returns
_Unable to resolve identifier copy_n_
and
_Unable to resolve identifier begin_

Is there also a way of using the second parameter of copy to get three numbers?

Comment: @user2136754 I think your code was supposed to be `inputFile.begin()`.